# How to make scroll buttons visible automatically when number of records increased in Ionic 4?

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular6, ionic4

I'm creating Ionic 4 plus Angular App , in that I make div scrollable .
Now I want to show scrollable top and bottom button as per the records increase then down arrow scrollable button visible and when we on last records then up arrow scrollable button visible to move top.

Comment: Hi @gaus please check this link https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-how-to-scroll-to-top-bottom-using-ion-content-scroll-events/ hope this will helpful for you. thank you.

Comment: @videsh, Actually i want to div as scrollable , not entire page as scrollable

Comment: okay got it so for that case you can use ion-scroll element this element is provide you the scroll event something like that  <ion-scroll scrollY="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></ion-scroll>

Comment: ion-scroll not available in ionic 4.

Comment: So you can use CSS instead of ion-scroll for that case. if you want i'll provide you the css also.

Comment: yes sure.Thank You.

Comment: what do you mean by  "I want to show scrollable top and bottom button as per the records increase" do you want a button which allows you to go to the bottom of the list ?

Answer (score 0):

could give this a whirl

.html

```
<div id="myFixZone">
    <ion-list>
    <!--...content...-->
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

.css

```
#myFixZone {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi @gaus use div instead of ion-scroll

```
div[scrollx=true], div[scrolly=true] {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}

div[scrollx=true] {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

div[scrolly=true] {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Thank you.